# Definite Integral

Tags: integral-equations

I am not able to do the following integration.

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{a} x\sin^2 \left(\frac{n \pi x}{a} \right)dx
\end{equation}

It shows an error that "more input is needed".

The mathematica code that I wrote is

```
R = Range[1, 10];
X = Integrate[x.[Sin[R.\[Pi].x/a]]^2, {x, 0, a}]
```

Comment: Please copy the Mathematica code that you tried.

Comment: Maybe you mean this: `Integrate[x (Sin[n \[Pi] x/a])^2, {x, 0, a}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
Evaluate for range of `n`

```
solution = Integrate[x*Sin[n*π*x/a]^2, {x, 0, a}]
Table[solution, {n, 0, 4}]

(* {Indeterminate, a^2/4, a^2/4, a^2/4, a^2/4} *)
```

Replace `.` with `*`.

```
Integrate[x*Sin[n*π*x/a]^2, {x, 0, a}]
```

$$ -\frac{a^2 \left(-2 \pi ^2 n^2+2 \pi  n \sin (2 \pi  n)+\cos (2 \pi  n)-1\right)}{8 \pi ^2 n^2}$$

Comment: I want n to represent integers from 0 to some n. So the sin(2 \pi n) and Cos(2 \pi n) terms would take the respective values.

Comment: `Sin[2 n π]` is `0` for all `n`. `Cos[2 n π]` is `1` for all `n`. So the answer is `a^2/4` for all integers `n`.

Comment: I get that. But I want to input this info in Mathematica. So that I get the final result.

Comment: `Simplify[Integrate[x*Sin[n*\[Pi]*x/a]^2, {x, 0, a}], 
 n \[Element] Integers]`